# How can I show all the methods that are available in my WCF in a dropdown

Tags: wcf, methods

How can I show all the methods that are available in my WCF in a dropdown. I need to show only those methods that are exposed to the client. I have the following code working, but it displays much more methods than expected. Seems it displays all.

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(IntlService.ClientDataServiceClient).GetMethods();

//// sort methods by name
Array.Sort(methods,
        delegate(MethodInfo methods1, MethodInfo methods2)
        { return methods1.Name.CompareTo(methods2.Name); });

foreach (var method in methods)
{
    string methodName = method.Name;
    ddlMethods.Items.Add(methodName);
}
```

How can I restrict the display to show only the ones that I defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to get only methods defined by your class, in this case, `IntlService.ClientDataServiceClient`, then alter your call to `GetMethods()` like this:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(IntlService.ClientDataServiceClient).GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

If you're looking to get only methods that are declared as service methods, then you'll need to examine the attributes on the methods:

```
MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(IntlService.ClientDataServiceClient).GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

// sort here...

foreach( var method in methods )
{
    if( method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute), true).Length == 0 )
        continue;

    string methodName = method.Name;
    ddlMethods.Items.Add(methodName);
}
```

Comment: I tried both the above code, but I don't get any result. now nothing comes up in dropdown. What can be the reason?

Comment: replace the `IntlService.ClientDataServiceClient` in the `typeof()` with the name of your contract (probably an interface... `IntlService.IClientDataService`?) and you should get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I got all the user methods now. Well, this pops another question. How do we get the list of parameters of the selected WCF method? I know, I am asking too much but I know gurus like you don't mind :)

Comment: The `MethodInfo` class has a method called `GetParameters()`. That's what you're looking for.

Comment: I was able to find that out but I got stuck on how will I find if the parameter is .net type or some custom type (some class type)? If custom type then I need to show all the attributes that user needs to set the value for. Should I post this question separately?

Comment: Yes, probably. You're off into the wide world of reflection here, and it seems like you're attempting to dynamically set up a form based on the parameters of a method. It's a sizable project you're embarking on here.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var method in methods)
{
   // Add the line below
   if (method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OperationContractAttribute)).Length > 0)
   {
      string methodName = method.Name;
      ddlMethods.Items.Add(methodName);
   }
}
```

Comment: It should be 
if (method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute), true).Length > 0)
but it doesn't return any method at all.

Comment: System.ServiceModel namespace inclusion was implied.