# Not able to filter WCF methods for dynamically created proxy

Tags: wcf, dynamic, methods

Some months back I was working on a project to display the WCF methods and thier parameters in a dropdown. At that time I was creating a proxy using Add Service Reference and hardcoded the service interface in the code. 
[How can I show all the methods that are available in my WCF in a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169096/how-can-i-show-all-the-methods-that-are-available-in-my-wcf-in-a-dropdown)
But when I try to create the proxy dynamically to do the same, the below code doesn't work. Please help me to show only the methods that was defined by me.

```
// Using Dynamic Proxy Factory by Vipul Modi @ Microsoft
DynamicProxyFactory factory = new DynamicProxyFactory(txtService.Text);

// endpoints.            
string sContract = "";

foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in factory.Endpoints)
{
    sContract = endpoint.Contract.Name;      //this is the service interface name, IAccountInfoService         
}
DynamicProxy proxy = factory.CreateProxy(sContract);
Type proxyType = proxy.ProxyType;

MethodInfo[] methods = proxyType.GetMethods();
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    //if (method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OperationContractAttribute), true).Length == 0)
    //    continue;
    string methodName = method.Name;
    ddlMethods.Items.Add(methodName);
}
```

The code commented method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OperationContractAttribute), true).Length doesn't work. It doesn't show any method. If I comment it out, then the result is all methods and variables. I want to restrict it to only user defined methods.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know anything about DynamicProxyFactory but looking at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx it makes me think that

1) the proxy doesnt actually emit methods with the attribute.  it doesn't seem to have a need to though i suppose you could tweak the code on your own to make that happen.

2) if you just want a list of method names, it seems you can get that from factory.Contracts

Comment: I actually want to get the method names and then the parameter list for each method that is defined in the service contract. Using ContractDescription and OperationDescription I can get the list of methods but not sure how to get the parameters?